# In Keynote, what are chapters and how do I create them?

Tags: keynote

I would like to know what chapters in keynote are and how you generate them.

NOTE: I first encountered these options when I made a keynote recording and it asked me stuff about making chapters.

An other application where I encountered the chapter option was in podcast producer where it askes me if I want to integrate chapters.

I am trying to make a podcast. Inserting chapters like the ones found in some youtube videos would be great for making it easier for the audience to skip stuff they already know.

Answer (score 1):

Chapters in an audio recording are exactly like chapters on a DVD. Many podcasts use chapters in the audio file to allow the listener to listen to specific topics or sections of the show. If you made a keynote podcast about programming an iOS app, you could chapter each project, or a unique aspect of using Xcode, or more.

Answer (score 0):

A chapter in this context would be like chapters on a DVD. When you press the skip ahead button it will jump directly to the next chapter marker. I don't see anything in Keynote that refers to chapters, so I suspect this is part of Podcast Producer.